# Why not all built-in constructor functions have a character property symbol.species

Tags: javascript

Why not all built-in constructor functions have a character property `Symbol.species`. And separately for `Array`, for example, JavaScript developers created a `Symbol.species`

Comment: Why would you expect them to have one? What do you think its purpose would be?

Comment: What makes you think that `Array[Symbol.species]` is special?